# Possible ways to get parameter values of a function in c#

Tags: c#, stack-trace, system.reflection

if (X) is called by (Y) and exception is in (X) then we should report both (X) and (Y) with parameters. I am using Postsharp for this and For (X) "public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)" is raised and i can get the arguments from MethodExecutionArgs but after that i need to have one more level of info ie (Y) with parameters and values

By doing the code below i can get the calling method (Y)

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
MethodBase CallingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod();
```

and the parameters of the underline method can also be extracted out. But the question is How do i get the values of that arguments? and What are the possible alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if (X) is called by (Y) and exception is in (X) then we should report both (X) and (Y) with parameters. I am using Postsharp for this and For (X) "public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)" is raised and i can get the arguments from MethodExecutionArgs but after that i need to have one more level of info

Comment: Y knows it's own parameters. Let Y report them.

Comment: can we make it work by any other way

Comment: If there is no meaningfull way to handle the exception in X, and yes, even logging is some way of "handling", then don't handle it there. Let the exception "bubble up" until you have enough information (i.e. the parameters in Y) to handle the exception properly.

Comment: @Corak What if bubbling is there and logging at each step is required too then it can be achieved but we will have multiple logs for one exception, which will be a problem to log? that was the reason for my question as only one logging record is required